# How do I take off cursed items?

Tags: adom

I made the mistake of wearing an amulet without identifying it, and now it turns out I can't take it off. I can't tell what effect it has while I'm wearing it, but it doesn't seem to have killed me yet. Even so, I would like to remove it until it can be properly identified.

How can I go about removing the cursed status, or short of that, how can I take it off despite its cursed status?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Removing Cursed Status**

- Scroll of Uncursing
- Remove Curse Spell
- Praying to your deity
- Dipping the item into a potion of holy water will bless the item, which also results in the cursed status being removed.

**Unequiping Cursed Gear**

- Destroying the item will result it in being, well, destroyed. Which in turn will result in it being unequiped.

  - Scroll of Item Destruction
  - Traps
  - The Tower of Eternal Flames
  - Punishment from your god

[(source)](http://ancardia.wikia.com/wiki/Losing_cursed_stuff)

Comment: Of course, I died before you posted this answer.